# Avoid 'confused deputy' with codepipeline role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

In the trust policy of a pipeline role I'm trying to add conditions uaing aws:SourceAccount and aws:SourceArn to make it so the role can only be used via a specific pipeline, like so.

```
  AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
    Version: "2012-10-17"
    Statement:
      - Action: sts:AssumeRole
        Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          Service: codepipeline.amazonaws.com
        Condition:
          StringEquals:
              aws:SourceAccount: !Ref AWS::AccountId
          ArnLike:
              aws:SourceArn:
                - "arn:aws:codepipeline:eu-west-1:111111111:mypipeline"
```

Neither condition works together or alone. The Pipeline arn is correct. With any combination of the above, the pipeline can't assume the role.

Comment: Your trust policy seems reasonable to me. I'm assuming the pipeline is successful if you have zero conditions. Might need a AWS support ticket to investigate this. BTW I think typical guidance is to use (only) the aws:SourceArn condition, but you probably know that already.

Comment: Indeed. it works with no conditions. But neither or both of the two listed, despite them being accurate. Frustratingly we don't get to see the request context and it seems hit or miss as to wether the aws service passes the sourceAccount or sourceArn. For example cloudformation does, as does codebuild. It makes no sense in that context that codepipeline does not. When you think about it, it's poor that you can't directly say only this pipeline can use this role.

Comment: I agree, and it's good that you're thinking about these things. Most people aren't even aware.

Comment: I believe you've spotted a bug! I too am reproducing this. Have you considered posting on  AWS forums? [There's nothing listed yet for this](https://repost.aws/search/questions?globalSearch=codepipeline+role)

Comment: @RonanCunningham are you able to get it done? I am also facing same issue

Comment: @sandeepkrishna - no, but I recreated the issue in my account and have raised a case with AWS. I will update with any response

Comment: I checked with AWS support, and it is not supported and not considered a bug—the reasons were unclear to me due to some language challenges.